# Talend - why does connection fail to find com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: jdbc, talend

I am getting this error when I do a [Check] from the Db Connection:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

The connection has "Db Version" set to use "Microsoft" [image: Connection].

The mssql-jdbc.jar shows as installed in the "Module View" [image: Module View]

The jar appears under temp\dbWizard -- which seems odd.  This is even after removing it and then reinstalling it.[image: File Explorer]

If I [Revert to Context] and change "Db Version" to "Open source JTDS", then do [Check], it succeeds.

This worked fine previously so I don't know what got broken.

Comment: Which version of Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver are you using, and which Java version are you using for Talend?

Comment: Talend-Studio install shows \jre1.8.0_131 folder.  mssdql-jdbc.jar was from downloading the latest at MS "sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu.tar".

Comment: SQL JDBC 6.0 is not the latest though, but it is not the problem I was thinking of though (although you still want to check if you're using the right one for your Java version).

Comment: You gave me an idea.  I checked and confirmed that 6.0 doesn't support SQL Server 2005 -- which these old databases, are.  So, I deleted the jar from temp\dbWizard, downloaded the 4.1 version and installed it.  It appears in that same temp\dbWizard location but the connection still fails with the same error.  It really looks like something isn't working given it ends up in that strange folder.  But it continues to show "Installed" in the Modules View.

Comment: Or, maybe bag this and just switch to the open source jar.  Not sure what I lose by doing so...

Comment: I recommend you use the open source jtds driver. We've had some issues with the microsoft driver in my company.